# Epoch time for a particular time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, epoch

I am quite new in JavaScript.

I was wondering how to get the epoch time for a particular time say 8:00 AM for today or any other day?

Comment: A small addition to the answers here: I think date and time handling in JavaScript is quite confusing when it comes to timezones. I suggest using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myDate = new Date("July 1, 1978 02:30:00"); // Your timezone!
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
document.write(myEpoch);
```

The example above gives the following output:

```
268088400
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you choose to use "July 1, 1978 02:30:00" specifically as an example.

Comment: it's my elder sister's birth date. :)

Comment: Please , select answer as a right answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var epochTimeNow = Date.now(); //UTC timestamp in milliseconds
var seconds = epochTimeNow/1000; //get
```

Pollyfill

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

Comment: For IE 8 or earlier you can use the polyfil at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now